# Android discovering same app UUID devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, bluetooth-device-discovery

I am using bluetooth adapter to discover bluetooth devices. The search displays all devices (iOS , Android, Speakers etc) which are available in surrounding with Bluetooth turned ON.

My App sends and receive data, so installed on two different Android Devices, app can perform a chat functionality, provided both apps are using same App UUID.

Is it possible that when I perform the device discovery/search, I only limit discovery to those devices which are **Android** and are using my App i.e. my **App UUID** and not to show all other bluetooth devices.

I know this happens in iOS using characteristic UUID.

Appreciate Response.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

1) First you're doing an Inquiry (search) of all nearby devices
2) for each device enumerated, do a Discovery (SDP) on it to gather all its services/profiles; If you found the one you're searchnign for, display it, otherwise forget it...

PS: I have no idea about selecting Android devices only... You can use the CoD (Class Of Device) but not sure that you can separate Android from other "smartphones"...